# Strange registry value for PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE for Intel and AMD processor

Tags: windows, registry, 64-bit, processor

I was having a small task to find whether the system is 32-bit or 64-bit machine during installation?
I figured the way by getting the value of registry `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` located in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\` folder but I was surprised to find that value was `AMD64` but my processor was `Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel`?
So why `AMD64` for `Intel64` bit processor?

Comment: Because it's AMD that created the 64bit extensions for the x86 instruction set, and Intel licensed them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) The 64 bit extensions to the *x86* architecture were invented and first implemented by *AMD*.

That's why you get `AMD64` and also the registry key is `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` which tells the underlying architecture used by processor which is off course `AMD64`.

For information,
Intel laggards to the *64 bit* architecture because they were hoping to transition away from *x86* architecture and move towards *IA64*. *IA64* already existed in the form of the *Itanium* and *Intel* was hoping to transition towards that. Despite being a far better and more efficient architecture, lacking the inherent design flaws of *x86*, it suffered through lack of compatibility and it never took off as excepted in the commercial space. *AMD* on other hand, effectively forced *Intel's* by introducing the **Sledgehammer**, which was effectively a *64bit* chip based on the *x86* architecture. Hence the name **AMD64**.